# React Redux state stop changing after render of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So , Basically I am new to react and I am stuck in situation where I want to fetch more data from an API with sending page numbers when I click on button, everything works perfectly  i am getting data and everything but the main issue comes when I click on of items it show the details of the game by rendering another component but when i close it and try to fetch more data by clicking on next button it doesn't work and doesn't update the redux store state anymore. and if don't open the detail by clicking on game item it works perfectly the redux store state changes and everything. i am new to this so i will appreciate everyone who can help me with it and hope i learn new things and please let me know if i have done anything wrong in my code or there's a better way to do it i will also appreciate that.

**PopularGames components**

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//ANIMATION AND STYLED
import styled from "styled-components";
import { motion, AnimatePresence, AnimateSharedLayout } from "framer-motion";

    //REDUX and ROUTER
    import {
      AllPopularGame,
      NextPage,
      PrevPage,
    } from "../Actions/popularGameActions";
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { Link, useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

    //COMPONENTS
    import Game from "./games";
    import GameDetail from "./gameDetail";
    
    const PopularGames = () => {
      //GETTNG PATH
      const Location = useLocation();
      const History = useHistory();
    
      const pathId = Location.pathname.split("/")[4];
    
      //Redux store
      const { allPopularGame, gameCount, currentPage } = useSelector(
        (state) => state.popular
      );
      //No of pages
      const totalPage = Math.ceil(gameCount / 36);
      //STATES
      const [totalPages] = useState(totalPage);
    
      //SCROLL TO TOP
      useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }, [currentPage]);
    
      //Handlers
      const PrevHandler = () => {
        if (currentPage <= 1) {
          return;
        } else {
          dispatch(PrevPage());
          History.push(`/popular/games?page=${currentPage - 1}`);
        }
      };
    
      const NextHandler = () => {
        if (currentPage <= totalPages) {
          return;
        } else {
          dispatch(NextPage());
          History.push(`/popular/games?page=${currentPage + 1}`);
        }
      };
      //Fetch all popular games
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(AllPopularGame(currentPage));
      }, [dispatch, currentPage]);
    
      // {`${currentPage} /popular/games/${popularGames.id}`}
      return (
        <Popular>
          <h2>Popular Games </h2>
          <AnimateSharedLayout type="crossfade">
            <AnimatePresence>
              {pathId && <GameDetail pathId={pathId} curPage={currentPage} />}
            </AnimatePresence>
            <Games>
              {allPopularGame.map((popularGames) => (
                <Link
                  to={`/popular/games/${currentPage}/${popularGames.id}`}
                  key={popularGames.id}
                >
                  <Game
                    name={popularGames.name}
                    img={popularGames.background_image}
                    rating={popularGames.rating}
                    id={popularGames.id}
                    key={popularGames.id}
                    released={popularGames.released}
                  />
                </Link>
              ))}
            </Games>
          </AnimateSharedLayout>
          <Page>
            <Button onClick={PrevHandler}>
              <span>Prev</span>
            </Button>
            <p>{currentPage}</p>
            <Button onClick={NextHandler}>
              <span>Next</span>
            </Button>
          </Page>
        </Popular>
      );
    };
```

**GAME ACTION**

```
import axios from "axios";
//Import URL
import { allPopularGamesURL } from "../Api/api";

export const AllPopularGame = (page) => async (dispatch) => {
  const fetchPopularGames = await axios.get(allPopularGamesURL(page));
  dispatch({
    type: "POPULAR_GAMES",
    payload: {
      popular: fetchPopularGames.data.results,
      count: fetchPopularGames.data.count,
    },
  });
};

export const NextPage = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "NEXT_PAGE",
  });
};
export const PrevPage = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "PREV_PAGE",
  });
};
```

**GAME REDUCER**

```
const initState = {
  allPopularGame: [],
  gameCount: null,
  currentPage: 1,
};

export const PopularGames = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "POPULAR_GAMES": {
      return {
        ...state,
        allPopularGame: action.payload.popular,
        gameCount: action.payload.count,
      };
    }
    case "NEXT_PAGE": {
      return {
        ...state,
        currentPage: state.currentPage + 1,
      };
    }
    case "PREV_PAGE": {
      return {
        ...state,
        currentPage: state.currentPage - 1,
      };
    }
    default: {
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: If you don't already have the redux dev tools and browser extension installed and setup then I suggest you do. After clicking to view the game details and navigating back, are you able to verify your pagination actions are dispatched? Can you try manually dispatching those actions from the dev tool to see if actions/reducers function? What debugging have you already tried?

Comment: i have redux dev tools and i have tried skip and navigating back but cant really figured out anything and as i mentioned this thing is happening after i open the detail component and close it.